# Homework Question: Setting Up An Integral for Simple Physics Problem

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics, electromagnetism

[image]

In this problem I am trying to find $E_{x}$(the electric field of at the origin). So far I have the following:

$dE_{x} = -k\frac{dq}{a^2}cos(\theta).$ This is the basic componet of the electric field in the x-direction.

Knowing the charge density is: $\lambda =\frac{Q}{L}$ and $\lambda = \frac{dq}{d\theta}$

So by doing a little algebra I get: $\lambda \cdot d\theta = dq$.

Subbing things in: $E_{x} = -\int \frac{k\lambda}{a^2}cos(\theta)d\theta$.

Above is where I am stuck. The solution is: $-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\lambda cos(\theta)k}{a}d\theta$.

What substitutions am I failing at? I don't really understand how they got there...

Comment: Notice that your units are wrong for the derivative $\lambda = \frac{dq}{d\theta}$ ? $\theta$ is dimensionless, but you need a length.

Comment: So would this be $\lambda = \frac{dq}{dx}$? Then how would I get $\theta$?

Comment: $\frac{dq}{dx}$ is still wrong. What kind of length (which direction, etc) do you want?

Comment: @MD_ $\lambda= dq/dl$. A little bit of charge will just be $dq$. What about the little bit of length? We're on a circular arc, so using $s= r\theta$, we get a 'little' bit of length by taking a 'little' bit in theta, hence $dl= ds= rd\theta$. Then $\lambda= dq/(r d\theta)= 1/r \cdot dq/d\theta$.

Comment: I see! So it’s the change in arc length. I’ll work on it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charge is uniformly distributed in the wire. The wire is a circular arc. A circle has circumference $2\pi r= 2\pi a$. We only want a quarter of it, so $\pi a/2$. Then the charge density is
$$
\lambda= \dfrac{q}{\frac{\pi}{2} r}= -2.9 \cdot 10^{-6}
$$
But then $dq= \lambda \;ds= \lambda R d\theta$. Then we have
$$
E_x= - \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{k\cos \theta}{R^2} \;dq= - \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{k\lambda R\cos \theta}{R^2} \;d\theta= - \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{k\lambda \cos \theta}{R} \;d\theta
$$